# what else could be if it is not blank, NaN or empty?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, return-value

I have some rows on a data frame with no value. I want to select them but I cannot find out their values.

I have tried `.isnull()`, `isempty()`, `==''`, `=="''"`, `== 0`

All respond false.
What else could their values be?

Comment: can you show us your dataframe?

Comment: you can retrieve the object through indexing, and thus use `type(df.loc[row, 'col'])`.

Comment: sorry, I could not able to formate the new lines for some reasons.

Comment: @ignoring_gravity, Here is my code 
`new_df['Close Date']`
`0 2015-03-23 08:47:55`
`1 2018-09-29 07:00:08`
`2 2016-01-21 07:40:59`
`3 2015-03-23 06:22:52'
` 4 ... `
`3881`
`3882`
`3883`
`3884`
`3885`
`Name: Close Date, Length: 3886, dtype: object` 
Then I convert to df 
`a=pd.DataFrame(new_df['Close Date'])`
`a[a['Close Date'].isnull()]`
I got an empty table Close Date

Comment: @Ginger19 What's the output of `a['Close Date'].loc[3881]`?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works -

**null_columns=df.columns[df.isnull().any()]**

**df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)][null_columns]**

Comment: Thanks. It does not work. The column 'Close Date' is not selected. It shows that this column has no empty or null.